# ContentAdapter Sqlite database multiple databases

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

This is actually two questions:

1. If i expose my SQLite as a `ContentProvider` in my application it will work in an asynchronous fashion ?
2. Imagine i have the following tables in my database:

`TableChats
TableChatMessages`

and i also have a class
`Message`

To work with `ListViews` and have those list views use data from the `ContentProvider` must that data returned be a Cursor ? or is it possible to query for all messages in a chat and return an array of `Message`. 
Sorry i know this may be a dumb question but i'm new to android development and the concept of `ContentProvider` and `ListViews` and how to connect them isn't quite yet clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge

1. A `content provider` manages access to a central repository of data which shared between multiple applications. Normally all methods access the data work on the `UI thread`. If you want asynchronous, they suggest to use [`CursorLoader`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#SimpleQuery).
2. You can query all messages, get data from `Cursor` and put to your `Message` object.

Sample:

```
       Cursor sampleCursor = getContentResolver().query("Your query");
    ArrayList<Message> list;
        if(sampleCursor!=null){
    while(sampleCursor.moveNext()){
        Message item = new Message();

        item.sender = sampleCursor.getString(senderColumnIndex);
        item.messageBody= sampleCursor.getString(messageBodyColumnIndex);
    list.add(item);
    }}
//Pass your list to your adapter.
```

Or directly pass your cursor using `CursorAdapter`